# Form data sent from the front end has different result in controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I was having trouble updating my product using entity framework.
When I submitted my form, from the developer's tools, I can confirm that the form is sending [0].Id = 3.

But when I was debugging the model, the debug.print keeps printing 0 as the Id.

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Details(IList<Item> model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Debug.Print(model[0].Id.ToString()); //This prints 0
            Debug.Print(model[0].Name);// This prints correctly
            Debug.Print(model[0].Size);// This prints correctly
            Debug.Print(model[0].RetailPrice.ToString());// This prints correctly
            Debug.Print(model[0].IsAvailable.ToString());// This prints correctly
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Count(); i++)
            {
                ndb.Entry(model[0]).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                ndb.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ProductIndex");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Anyone has any idea why?

EDIT:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Size)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].RetailPrice)
            <td>
                @Model[i].Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model[i].Size
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model[i].RetailPrice
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBox("["+i+"].IsAvailable", Model[i].IsAvailable)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
}
```

And as I have mentioned earlier, the form submit from the developer's tool showed the correct Id, but when it came to the controller, it always gives me 0 as the Id.

Comment: If everything else works except for that field, then I have a feeling Id does not have a setter. Do you have a setter on the `Id` property or just a getter?

Comment: Can you add `Details` view code? I'm guessing you dont have `ID` defined in the view

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti hi, Id property has getter and setter, since I'm using snippets I won't miss it.

Comment: @TheUknown Hi, I have put the details view.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed the `ID` field in your View. you should add  `ID` field in the View as hidden field or bind it to the property.

It's also not recommended to use EF objects in the view. create a Custom View Model instead.

Comment: Hi, I have put the Id field in my View, though using Custom View Model might work, I am still curious as why the Id keeps returning 0 in my controller yet it shows the correct number on the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
```

to below(Either both or the 2nd one should work. Haven't tested it. But you need to use `Model`)

```
@Html.HiddenFor(@Model[i].Id)
```

OR

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
```

Comment: Sorry but it still doesnt work, I dont think my view is the issue, because the form is already submitting the correct Id, the only problem is that when the Id comes to the controller, it always returns 0.

Comment: Can you check in fiddler what data is sent?

Comment: Are you passing your model to the view?  `@model IList<Item> //first line of the details view`? What does `Item` model look like, can you add the model and other relevant code?

Comment: Yes, I put it as my model, I really don't know what the problem is, anyway I have solved it using custom view models, @esiprogrammer is right, you shouldn't use EF Model for View Model, there is often a case where something is wrong. Anyway thanks a lot TheUknown